# Necessary and sufficient condition for a matrix to have postive eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a question that requires the condition for $k$ for the below matrix to have positive eigenvalues.

$\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 1\\
    1 & k\\
\end{bmatrix}$

How to do it ?

**Edit:** I need a generalized answer for any `nxn` matrix not just 2x2.

Comment: Emmm, maybe compute the ******* eigenvalues?

Comment: @copper.hat how will you compute for the above matrix when the matrix is not complete?

Comment: The same way you would compute eigenvalues if the value of $k$ was a number. Compute the determinant as a function of some variable and $k$.

Comment: @copper.hat what would you do for a nxn matrix isn't there a general condition ?

Comment: In general, unless there is some special structure (such as being triangular, or having some regular form) there is no simple formulation of when a matrix is or is not positive definite.

Comment: @copper.hat I guess I was looking for the criterion for symmetric matrices.

Comment: It still involves computing the determinant, so if there are variables involved, it may still be a computational burden.

Comment: @copper.hat still Sylvester's criterion does the job.

Comment: It is a good solution here. But just computing the eigenvalues is basically the same amount of work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Sylvester's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion). It works for symmetric matrices of any dimension.

Comment: Yes! this is what I was looking for "The real-symmetric matrix A is positive definite if and only if all the leading principal minors of A are positive." - Sylvester's criterion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To compute the eigenvalues for a matrix $M$ you can find the determinant of the difference between $M$ and the matrix with $\lambda$ on the diagonal, that is $\lambda I$.  Then set this equation to $0$ and solve for the values of $\lambda$.
Like the following:
$$det(M-\lambda I)=0$$

From this you should get an equation in $k$, and I think you can take it from there.